# Spark persistent view on a partition parquet file

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

In Spark, is it possible to create a persistent view on a partitioned parquet file in Azure BLOB? The view must be available when the cluster restarted, without having to re-create that view, hence it cannot be a temp view.

I can create a temp view, but not the persistent view. Following code returns an exception.

`spark.sql("CREATE VIEW test USING parquet OPTIONS (path \"/mnt/folder/file.c000.snappy.parquet\")")`

`ParseException:  mismatched input 'USING' expecting {'(', 'UP_TO_DATE', 'AS', 'COMMENT', 'PARTITIONED', 'TBLPROPERTIES'}(line 1, pos 23)`

Big thank you for taking a look :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you used is working for temporary views but not persistent views. I faced the same error `ParseException:  mismatched input 'USING' expecting {'(', 'UP_TO_DATE', 'AS', 'COMMENT', 'PARTITIONED', 'TBLPROPERTIES'}`, when I tried to reproduce this using a similar syntax.

- Using the syntax provided for the `CREATE VIEW` in [this official Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-view), I created a persistent view using data source (using my mount point and a csv file in it) in the following way:

```
spark.sql("CREATE VIEW demo2 as select * from csv.`/mnt/repro/op.csv`")
```

**Output Image:**

[image]

- So, you can modify your query to the following statement:

```
CREATE VIEW test as select * from parquet.`/mnt/folder/file.c000.snappy.parquet\`
```